# Create index in Elastic Search by Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I used following code for creating index in Elastic Search,
Default JAVA API:

```
Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", "myClusterName").put("client.transport.sniff", true).build();
Client client = new TransportClient(settings).addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost", 9200));
CreateIndexRequestBuilder createIndexRequestBuilder = client.admin().indices().prepareCreate("test1");
CreateIndexResponse response = createIndexRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();
System.out.println(response.isAcknowledged());
```

REST Service:

```
HttpURLConnection con = null;
try
{
    String url = "http://localhost:9200/test2";

    URL resturl = new URL(url);
    con = (HttpURLConnection) resturl.openConnection();

    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setRequestMethod("PUT");
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try
    {
        if (con.getInputStream() != null)
        {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        if (con.getErrorStream() != null)
        {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getErrorStream()));
        }
    }
    if (in == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to read response from server");
    }
    StringBuffer decodedString = new StringBuffer();
    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
    {
        decodedString.append(line);
    }
    in.close();
    System.out.println("4");
    Integer responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println(responseCode);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
    if (con != null)
    {
        con.disconnect();
    }
}
```

By using REST API, I am able to create index. By default JAVA API, 
I am getting the following Exception.

```
org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: No node available
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:202)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.InternalTransportIndicesAdminClient.execute(InternalTransportIndicesAdminClient.java:85)
at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractIndicesAdminClient.create(AbstractIndicesAdminClient.java:200)
at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.create.CreateIndexRequestBuilder.doExecute(CreateIndexRequestBuilder.java:206)
at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:62)
at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:57)
at ElasticSearch.createIndex(ElasticSearch.java:121)
at ElasticSearch.main(ElasticSearch.java:157)
```

Please guide me where I made mistake. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The port for TransportClient(via java API) is different than Http
By default, transportClient port is 9300

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Still I am getting the same exception.

Comment: It works fine now. I made a small mistake as I used 9300. But in config I updated port number.

Answer (score 10):

With replicas and shards settings:

```
Settings indexSettings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
                 .put("number_of_shards", 1)
                 .put("number_of_replicas", 1)
                 .build();
CreateIndexRequest indexRequest = new CreateIndexRequest(index, indexSettings);
client.admin().indices().create(indexRequest).actionGet();
```

Comment: Thanks :), nb : the class ImmutableSettings is removed: for the newer version, use Settings.builder(). For more info : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33115504/is-immutablesettings-removed-in-elastic-search

Answer (score 6):

Given that you have you client shouldn't you be able to do this then:

```
CreateIndexResponse createResponse = client.admin().indices().create(createIndexRequest("test1")).actionGet();
```

Comment: I would just add that the `createIndexRequest` method is `Requests.createIndexRequest("test1")`

Answer (score 3):

Using JAVA High-Level Rest Client below code can be used to create Index.

```
 CreateIndexRequest request = new CreateIndexRequest("users");
        request.settings(Settings.builder()
                .put("index.number_of_shards", 3)
                .put("index.number_of_replicas", 2)
        );
        Map<String, Object> message = new HashMap<>();
        message.put("type", "text");   

        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("userId", message);
        properties.put("name", message);

        Map<String, Object> mapping = new HashMap<>();
        mapping.put("properties", properties);
        request.mapping(mapping);

        CreateIndexResponse indexResponse = client.indices().create(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        System.out.println("response id: "+indexResponse.index());
```

For further reference please read : 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-create-index.html#java-rest-high-create-index