# Is ImmutableSettings removed in Elastic-search?

Tags: elasticsearch

The ImmutableSettings class in the elastic-search project does not exist anymore. I found that the class was deleted.

"org.elasticsearch.common.settings.ImmutableSettings was deleted at 2015-05-26 05:41:12."

Would anyone give feedback on this? I still find many Q&As that include the class in the Stack Overflow.

- [How to write a test for Elasticsearch custom plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28221271/how-to-write-a-test-for-elasticsearch-custom-plugin)
- [Adding mapping to a type from Java - how do I do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22071198/adding-mapping-to-a-type-from-java-how-do-i-do-it)
- [Linkage error when using Elasticsearch client in Spring WebApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21043128/linkage-error-when-using-elasticsearch-client-in-spring-webapp)
- [Elasticsearch scala elastic4s settings from property file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26868602/elasticsearch-scala-elastic4s-settings-from-property-file/26897126#26897126)

Answer (score 26):

In ES 2.0, the `ImmutableSettings` class was indeed removed. [This issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/13151) mentions it and the [breaking changes documentation for 2.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/breaking_20_java_api_changes.html) also mention it.

Instead you can now use `Settings.builder()` instead of `ImmutableSettings.builder()`. The current implementation of the `Settings` class can be seen [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/148265bd164cd5a614cd020fb480d5974f523d81/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/settings/Settings.java)

All the questions that still use `ImmutableSettings` are questions about **pre-2.0 versions** of Elasticsearch.

Comment: The link is broken, new URL for this information is: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/breaking_20_java_api_changes.html

Comment: Thanks, updating the answer as well, just in case.